# Embed Google Calendar in React App

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a web app using React and I would like to implement a calendar. Is there any way I can embed Google calendar into my React app as opposed to *rendering* a calendar from scratch?

Comment: You may check this [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api) for `react-google-calendar-api` to manage your google calendar. Also, here's a [tutorial](https://blog.daftcode.pl/react-calendar-with-google-calendar-as-cms-tutorial-5f5d81e425a9) on how to implement React Calendar with Google Calendar as CMS. You need to set up a React project with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), create a React component, and fetch events from a Google Calendar using AJAX. You can see the [finished project on GitHub](https://github.com/daftcode/react-calendar-tutorial).